# Accessing Android Pay User's Transaction Log

Tags: android

I am trying to gain access to the user's Android Pay wallet for an app I'm developing. The goal is to monitor the expenses in a background service. I have looked all over online and cannot find any tutorials showing how to get a transaction log from the wallet. I'm not sure if this is something you can do, or not but I would assume you would be able to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So far, all the info I see says there either isn't a transaction log, or it's up to your bank and whether or not they'll share the info.  I read some sayign BoA doesn't share any info back, so it just shows up on your bank statement as a normal credit card transaction with the establishment.  USBank apparently will share some info and people can see some details.  I don't know for sure though, that's really what I was trying to look up when I found your questions.